# Display one piece of a multidimensional array while entering another from a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, multidimensional-array, sql-update

I need to be able to enter a String value, and have it input the id to that row on a table.

I'm trying to get something like a `select` tag in `HTML` to work in `Ruby`. However I need it to programmatically change when new rows are added to the table I'm pulling the values from.

The table itself looks something like this:

```
Locations
 id    location_cd
| 1  |         SLC|
| 2  |         LAS|
```

etc.

I used the Location class to pass these values from this table into an array. Here is the Location class.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.select_options
        self.all.sorted.collect{ |q| [q.id, q.location_cd]}
    end


end
```

Doing this gives me this multidimensional array when I call the select_options method.

```
[[1, "SLC"], [2, "LAS"]]
```

Here's what I have in the controller.

```
def edit
    @pallet = Pallet.find(params[:id])
    @locations = Location.all
  end

  def update
    @pallet = Pallet.find(params[:id])
    if @pallet.update_attributes(pallet_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Pallet Updated Successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @pallet.id)
    else
      @pallet_count = Pallet.count
      render('edit')
    end
  end
```

Pallet is the main class I'm pulling from, and I need to enter the location.id into the pallets table.

Here's what I have in edit.

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'index'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="pallets edit">
    <h2>Update Pallet</h2>

    <%= form_for(:pallet, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @pallet.id}) do |f| %>

        <%= render(:partial => "form", :locals => {:f => f}) %>

        <div class="form-buttons">
            <%= submit_tag("Update Pallet") %>
        </div>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

This will redirect it to the form, and here's what I have in my form. This is where the problem I'm running into is.

```
<table summary="Pallets from fields">
    <tr>
        <th><%= f.label(:destination) %></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.select(:destination, Location.select_options) %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Doing this will give me a list of the `id`s like this.

```
1
2
```

However I want a list of the `location_cd`s like this.

```
SLC
LAS
```

But I need it to be to the point where I can enter SLC, and in the database it would enter 1 instead.

To put this into the perspective of the `multidimensional array` I need to be able to enter the second value of `[[1, "SLC"]]` on the user side, and the first value(`1`) should be entered into the table.

Comment: It is not clear what do you need, but I guess change an order helps to correct UI representation and pass id instead of key: *[q.location_cd, q.id]*

Comment: What I need is to be able to display on the UI the location_cd, and when it is selected, then the id is what goes into the form. Any suggestions on how to make this more clear in the question itself?

Comment: yes, please try what I said above by changing method *self.select_options*

Comment: I changed the method from getting [q.location_cd, q.id] as an array, to just getting q.location_cd(if that's what you were suggesting) and on the UI it gets the location_cd column, but the input doesn't change anything in the table.

Comment: can you share Rails log in development include that POST request please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot of digging and I was able to find something that worked.

There is a helper that comes with rails called `options_for_select()`. What this does is it will take something like this

```
<%= select_tag(:destination, '<option value="1">SLC</option>...') %>
```

And it will auto-generate the options using a `multidimensional array`

Since I already had a `multidimensional array` by using the `select_options` method, I was able to use them both in conjunction with each other like so:

```
<td><%= select_tag(:destination, options_for_select(Location.select_options)) %></td>
```

This pulls up exactly what I needed, and appends the correct value to the database when selected.

Another method is without the options_for_select helper, but it would need to have a parameter for which row is selected available.

```
@pallet = Pallet.find(2)

<td><%= select(:pallet, :destination, Location.select_options) %></td>
```

The advantage of this one is that it automatically defaults to what was already there. This makes it easier for when you update something that isn't the location.